# Adding Metaboxes - so much code is there a shorter DRY way?

Tags: metabox

I added the following two metaboxes to my functions.php file and it works, but it's a lot of code.

### Question: Is there a shorter or simple way to do this without a plugin?

[image]

```
/**
 * Add custom fields to a specific WP page template & save it
*/

$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
  // check for a template type
  if ($template_file == 'template-testhome.php') { //this is the template change on real site

  // add the actions to add functions :: how many slides to show
   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'slidestoshow_create_post_meta_box' );
   add_action( 'save_post', 'slidestoshow_save_post_meta_box', 10, 2 );
   

  // add the actions to add functions :: type of slider infinite or not
   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'slidetype_create_post_meta_box' );
   add_action( 'save_post', 'slidetype_save_post_meta_box', 10, 2 );


//begin slides to show meta box
function slidestoshow_create_post_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'slidestoshow_meta_box', 'Slides to Show & Scroll (1-6)', 'slidestoshow_page_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function slidestoshow_page_meta_box( $object, $box ) { ?>
    <p>
        <label for="slides-to-show-scroll">Slides to Show & Scroll (1-6)</label>
        <!-- keep reference
        <textarea name="second-excerpt" id="second-excerpt" cols="60" rows="4" tabindex="30" style="width: 97%;"><?php echo wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Second Excerpt', true ), 1 ); ?></textarea>
        -->
       <input type="text" id="slides-to-show-scroll" name="slides-to-show-scroll" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Slides to Show Scroll', true ), 1 ); ?>" size="10" />
       <input type="hidden" name="slidestoshow_page_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); ?>" />
    </p>
<?php }
// end create the meta box for slides to show


//begin slide type meta box
function slidetype_create_post_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'slidetype_meta_box', 'Infinte (true or false)', 'slidetype_page_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function slidetype_page_meta_box( $object, $box ) { ?>
    <p>
        <label for="slide-type">Infinite (true or false)</label>
       <input type="text" id="slide-type" name="slide-type" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Slide Type', true ), 1 ); ?>" size="10" />
       <input type="hidden" name="slidetype_page_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); ?>" />
    </p>
<?php }
// end create the meta box for slides type


function slidestoshow_save_post_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['slidestoshow_page_meta_box_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slides to Show Scroll', true );
    $new_meta_value = stripslashes( $_POST['slides-to-show-scroll'] );

    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value )
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slides to Show Scroll', $new_meta_value, true );

    elseif ( $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slides to Show Scroll', $new_meta_value );

    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slides to Show Scroll', $meta_value );
}
//end the save for slides to show



function slidetype_save_post_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['slidetype_page_meta_box_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slide Type', true );
    $new_meta_value = stripslashes( $_POST['slide-type'] );

    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value )
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slide Type', $new_meta_value, true );

    elseif ( $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slide Type', $new_meta_value );

    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'Slide Type', $meta_value );
}
//end the save for slide type
```

Comment: use a framework for metaboxes, such as cmb2 (https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) - reduces the amount of code you need and also offers so much more flexibility with the types of inputs you can have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Leverage Functions**

You can extract the redundant code into reusable functions. For example, the last two functions could be rewritten like this. My resulting code is actually 2 lines longer, but it's much cleaner from a debugging standpoint. And, if there were a third custom field, this approach would definitely be shorter.

```
function slidestoshow_save_post_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {

    $nonce = 'slidestoshow_page_meta_box_nonce';
    $meta_label = 'Slides to Show Scroll';
    $meta_slug = 'slides-to-show-scroll';

    if ( !my_save_post_met_box( $post_id, $post, $meta_label, $meta_slug, $nonce ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
}

function slidetype_save_post_meta_box( $post_id, $post ) {

    $nonce = 'slidetype_page_meta_box_nonce';
    $meta_label = 'Slide Type';
    $meta_slug = 'slide-type';

    if ( !my_save_post_met_box( $post_id, $post, $meta_label, $meta_slug, $nonce ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
}

function my_save_post_meta_box( $post_id, $post, $meta_label, $meta_slug, $nonce ) {

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$nonce], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_label, true );
    $new_meta_value = stripslashes( $_POST[$meta_slug] );

    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value )
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_label, $new_meta_value, true );

    elseif ( $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_label, $new_meta_value );

    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_label, $meta_value );
}
```

And, you could reclaim your two lines by renaming your nonce to the same scheme as your slug. Something like this:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_slug . '_page_meta_box_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
```

**Use Arrays and Foreach Loops**

Your action hooks could be optimized like this. Again, more lines of code--with only two custom fields--but easier to read and debug.

```
$fnc_labels = array( 'slidestoshow', 'slidetype' );

foreach ( $fnc_labels AS $fnc_label ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', $fnc_label . '_create_post_meta_box' );
    add_action( 'save_post', $fnc_label . '_save_post_meta_box', 10, 2 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will study. I don't know much about php (or even wordpress, my old CMS is much easier -- create a field assign it and then use it if not empty takes seconds (Smarty 3)-- , my so-called php was copied and carefully looked at to follow exactly without knowing diddly squat. This is easier to understand now. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if there's any part you're confused by. And, as Gareth mentioned above, there are Custom Field plugins that take the burden of code off your hands.